# How do you run PHP script from command line on Windows 10

Tags: php

Hi I am learning to use PHP and I cannot figure out what to do from this texts.

From text:

> Go to the directory in which you saved your program, sayHello.php. You can do a director listing with dir to ensure that you're in the right directory. Once you're in the rea right directory, type this in your command line:

```
php sayHello.php
```

From what I did (Image):

[image: 1 screenshot]

EDIT

I am still having problem

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: When you are in that directory, you simple need just type that command: `php -f ./sayHello.php`

Comment: and when you typed "php sayHello.php" at the prompt and press Enter, what happened? Your image shows before you typed the command to run the script.

Comment: You can use cd /directory_you_saved_php_file

Comment: Make sure that the path to the php executable is in your environment path

Comment: Book never mentioned I need to install just open up Windows command line, open the correct directories, and type php sayHello.php

Comment: I guess it was implied. It's like working with Powerpoint, you can't make a presentation without the program. http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php

Comment: If you've installed xampp, then you do have PHP installed; and should just need to add it to your environment path

Answer (score 0):

**C**hange **d**ir to your developing folder:

> cd C:\Users\John\desktop\PHPDev

and from there invoke your program with PHP:

> php sayHello.php